# Setting Fields as required without using Required = True

Tags: visualforce, rerender, required-field, rendering

I have a SelectList from which user selects x,y,z recordName from Object 'A' in a pageBlock 'A' for which the an another pageblock 'B' gets rendered showing fields to insert into 'B' object. Out of all the fields in pageBlock B , few are mandatory so I added attribute ,required = true for them. But the problem occurs when user by mistake selects a wrong record in selectList under PageBlock A , and try to select correct value.

While doing that , the method inside controller should get called which Required fields' empty value are restricting.

Now , I can remove that by taking of "REQUIRED = TRUE" attribute from fields and do the validation in controller. But I am looking for a solution at UI side only such that I do not write any validation code inside my controller.

Is there a solution in SFDC only to do this ?

Comment: have you tried sing javascript?

Comment: I haven't. Before doing that , I would like to know if it can be done by SFDC , like restricting Required field's effect to some pageBlock or something else. Such that calling controller on SelectList Value Change should not get restricted because of 'Required = true' attribute in pageBlock B .

Answer (score 1):

There is one attribute `immediate="true"` using that it will skip all required field on page.

Use this to skip validation no need to remove required.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-immediate-attribute-on-commandlinks-and-commandbuttons.html)